# jquery UI tabs - drag & drop between tabs? design issue

Tags: jquery-ui, user-interface

so my company is finally going to rewrite some pages using jquery. They wanted some sort of a search panel, and when the user clicks on a search result (it could be a plan, a project, an invoice), the result details will open in a new tab. all is good.

each search result can contain documents and they want to be able to drag a document from say a plan in one tab to a project in another tab. also they want to able to view 2 things at the same time, say, compare 2 invoices side by side.

by the very nature of the tab widget you are supposed to only see 1 tab at a time, so my gut feeling is that the tab widget is not the right tool for this. the accordion does not fit either, since you cannot keep 2 sections opened at the same time.

any idea/suggestion for a better UI interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines of [this](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/droppable.html)?